# copy many files (same name) contained in different father folder

Tags: file, bash, unix, copy

I have a question about unix command line. I have many files like these:

```
/f/f1/file.txt

/f/f2/file.txt

/f/f3/file.txt

and so on.
```

I had like copy all `file.txt` with their **father folder** in another **folder g** like:

```
/g/f1/file.txt

/g/f2/file.txt

/g/f3/file.txt
```

I can't copy all content of `folder f` because in each `sub-folder f1, f2, ...` I have many other files that I don't want copy.

How could I do this with the command line? Eventually using a bash script?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Manual for `cp` shows this option -

```
--parents
              use full source file name under DIRECTORY
```

So if you are on `bash v4` you can do something like this -

```
[jaypal:~/Temp/f] tree
.
├── f1
│   ├── file.txt  # copy this file only with parent directory f1
│   ├── file1.txt
│   └── file2.txt
└── f2
    ├── file.txt  # copy this file only with parent directory f2
    ├── file1.txt
    └── file2.txt

2 directories, 6 files
[jaypal:~/Temp/f] mkdir ../g
[jaypal:~/Temp/f] shopt -s globstar
[jaypal:~/Temp/f] for file in ./**/file.txt; do cp --parents "$file" ../g ; done
[jaypal:~/Temp/f] tree ../g
../g
├── f1
│   └── file.txt
└── f2
    └── file.txt

2 directories, 2 files
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
This works like I wish!

Thanks even for other answers!

Comment: @fibon82: This is probably the simplest for your specific case, but have rsync in mind, as it's very powerful, particularly for more complex cases.

Comment: OK Karolos. Thank you too for your suggestion!

Comment: @Jaypal: +1 because I didn't know of --parents.

Comment: @Jaypal +1. Is it possible to replace the `for` loop by simply `cp --parents ./**/file.txt ../g`?

Comment: Sorry guys could you take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9035075/bash-script-copy-many-files-same-name-contained-in-different-father-folder)?
I'd like do a script with the Jaypal answer...

Answer (score 2):

tar is sometimes helpful for coping files: see the small test:

```
kent$  tree t g
t
|-- t1
|   |-- file
|   `-- foo ---->####this file we won't copy
|-- t2
|   `-- file
`-- t3
    `-- file
g

3 directories, 4 files

kent$  cd t

kent$  find -name "file"|xargs tar -cf - | tar -xf - -C ../g

kent$  tree ../t ../g
../t
|-- t1
|   |-- file
|   `-- foo
|-- t2
|   `-- file
`-- t3
    `-- file
../g
|-- t1
|   `-- file
|-- t2
|   `-- file
`-- t3
    `-- file
```

Comment: +1 I never thought using `tar` for a `move`. Excellent! The explanation is also very clear ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [rsync](http://ss64.com/bash/rsync.html). Assuming you are in '/',

```
rsync -r f/ g/ --include "*/" --include "*/file.txt" --exclude "*"
```

The first include is necessary to tell rsync to look inside the subdirectories (and counteract the last exclude). The second include selects the files you want to copy. The exclude makes sure that other files are not processed in /f that are not of the required pattern.

Note: in case you have symbolic links, rsync will copy the *link* and not the file the link points to, unless you specify `--copy-links`.

Example:

```
$ find f g -type f
f/f1/file.txt
f/f1/fileNew.txt
f/f2/file.txt
f/f3/file.txt
find: g: No such file or directory
$ rsync -r f/ g/ --include "*/" --include "*/file.txt" --exclude "*"
$ find f g -type f
f/f1/file.txt
f/f1/fileNew.txt
f/f2/file.txt
f/f3/file.txt
g/f1/file.txt
g/f2/file.txt
g/f3/file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems like it's going to help you :

```
find /f/ -name file.txt -execdir cp -R . /g/ \;
```

It locates all the files named file.txt in directory /f/, and then, using execdir (which is executed in the directory containing the matched file), copies the directory containing the file to directory /g/.

Comment: As far as I understand the command, it will copy the files to /g/ without preserving the relative paths, e.g. /g/f1/file.txt, and will _overwrite_ the existing file.txt, i.e. you end up win one file in /g/, the _last_ being copied. Did I miss something?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I edited the post from `cp` to `cp -R`, which obviously makes more sense when copying directories.

Comment: I don't think the issue is related to -R. I ran your code on Mac OS X (which is BSD unix), and end up with /g/ having the union of files, with any given name corresponding to the last file with that name copied.