# BASH SCRIPT: copy many files (same name) contained in different father folder

Tags: bash

I tried to turn into a bash script the Jaypal answer
([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9021931/copy-many-files-same-name-contained-in-different-father-folder/9022744#9022744))
in this way:

```
#!/bin/bash
pwd
mkdir -v ../g
shopt -s globstar
for file in ./**/file.txt
do
    echo "will copy $file"
    cp -v --parents "$file" ../g
done
```

But it doesn't work! (It only creates the empty folder g)
What could the problem be?
note: the script is in f folder

Thanks! :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [copy many files (same name) contained in different father folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9021931/copy-many-files-same-name-contained-in-different-father-folder)

Comment: I created a new question because I think this is different from the other...  
Here I ask **how turn into to a bash script the answer of Jaypal** that are commands for the command line...  
I don't ask **how copy the files**...  
However should I merge the 2 questions?

Comment: Please add in your script `pwd` (in the beginning) and `echo "$file"` within the loop. And then, give use the result. I did. Please run again and give results.

Comment: I obtain
    /home/fibon82/f

And then  the console does'nt reply...  
I think echo instruction is not reached...

Comment: OK I solved using only 1 * in `for file in ./*/file.txt`.  
In this way it seems work correctly.  
Thank you oHessling! :)

Comment: All right @fibon82. Please validate/enhance my last edit. See you soon.

Answer (score 1):

Answering the title question:

```
source_dir=/some/dir
target_dir=/some/other/dir
file_name=myfile.txt

cd $target_dir
while read path; do
  mkdir -p $(dirname $path)
  cp $source_dir/$path $target_dir/$path
done < <(cd $source_dir; find . -name $file_name -type f)
```

this duplicates all `$file_name` found under `$source_dir` into `$tagert_dir`

Regarding your second question (why your code doesn't work) perhaps  you don't have bash 4+ and so globstar is not working? Or maybe it returns something different that the relative path to the file (I thought, but I can't check since I have bash 3.2)

Answer (score 0):

*Since feature requests to [mark a comment as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82099/answering-comment-answered-questions) remain declined, I copy the above solution here.*

OK I solved using only 1 * in for file in ./*/file.txt. In this way it seems work correctly. Thank you oHessling! :) – fibon82